# How to convert a CSV file to MDB (Access Database) using C#

Tags: c#, database, csv

How to convert a CSV file to MDB (Access Database) using C#.I Really need this to add to my program, a code snippet would be very useful for this project. Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: did you checked the link of Eric J.?

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried? Usually it's best to include some example code in your question of how you're approaching the problem. Eric J's link looks like a good place to start.